# Generic type error for android java

Tags: java, android, generics, inheritance

So i am trying to create a generic type adapter as the android app i am developing involves creating a lot of recycler view adapters that are similar. I keep getting this compile error that says my shirt item cannot be converted to an item type.

```
error: incompatible types: Shirt cannot be converted to CAP#1
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends Item from capture of ? extends Item


class Shirt2ViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder<Shirt,OnRecyclerClickListener<? extends Item>> {

    public Shirt2ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBind(final Shirt item, @Nullable final OnRecyclerClickListener<? extends Item> listener) {
        descriptionText.setText(item.getmName());
        Glide.with(itemView.getContext()).load(item.getmImageUrl()).into(imageView);

        if (listener != null) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    listener.onItemClicked(view,item); // error is here 
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

OnRecyclerClickListener interface :

```
public interface OnRecyclerClickListener<T extends Item> extends BaseRecyclerListener {


public void onItemClicked(View itemView, T item);

}
```

BaseRecylcerInterface:

```
public interface BaseRecyclerListener {

}
```

Shirt class :

```
public class Shirt extends Item {



public Shirt() {}


public Shirt(String mName, String mColor, String mImageUrl) {
    super(mName,mColor,mImageUrl);
    }
}
```

Since my Shirt extends Item and in my OnRecyclerClickListener my T extends Item why does the compile error still occur? I haven posted the whole code for the generic recycler view as it would be quite messy so this is the viewholder class for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `BaseViewHolder<Shirt,OnRecyclerClickListener<? extends  Item>>` to `BaseViewHolder<Shirt,OnRecyclerClickListener<Shirt>>`, because `? extends Item` may not be `Shirt`.

Comment: it worked after changing however i dont seem to understand why because a shirt extends from item. Does this have to do with not being able to add to a a collection of type <? extends Item> ?

Comment: If you use ```? extends Item``` you actually mean that ```? extends Item``` is ```Shirt```, that's not true, the right one is ```Shirt``` is ```? extends Item```.

Comment: ```? extends Item``` cannot deduce that ```?``` is ```Shirt```.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this generic adapter [https://medium.com/@manojbhadane/android-generic-recyclerview-adapter-c0024161f1bc](http://medium.com/@manojbhadane/android-generic-recyclerview-adapter-c0024161f1bc)